# Python - Confused on Class Methods and Attributes

Tags: python, class

I am currently stuck trying to write a practice program.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

class Query:

    def __init__(self, feed_id, max_results):
        self.feed_id = feed_id
        self.max_results = max_results
        self.content_data = []  
        self.num_likes = []
        self.num_dislikes = []
        self.stats = []
        self.view_count = []

    def getQuery(self):
        web_obj = urllib.urlopen("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/%s?max- results=%s&time=today" % (self.feed_id, self.max_results))
        file = open('youtubequery.txt', 'w+')
        file.write(str(web_obj))
        for i in web_obj:
            file.write(i)
        with open("youtubequery.txt", "r") as myfile:
            file_2=myfile.read()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(file_2)

        for link in soup.find_all("content"):
            self.content_data.append(str(link.get("src")))
        print self.content_data
        for stat in soup.find_all("yt:statistics"):
            self.stats.append(str(stat.get("favoritecount")))
        print self.stats
        for views in soup.find_all("yt:statistics"):
            self.view_count.append(str(views.get("viewcount")))
        print self.view_count
        for numlikes in soup.find_all("yt:rating"):
            self.num_likes.append(str(numlikes.get("numlikes")))
        print self.num_likes
        for numdislikes in soup.find_all("yt:rating"):
            self.num_dislikes.append(str(numdislikes.get("numdislikes")))
        print self.num_dislikes

    # def __str__(self):
    #    print self.content_data
    #                           This doesn't work


#Class Video:(Query):

   #def __init__(self):
    #   pass

stuff = Query("top_rated", "5")
print stuff.__str__()
```

What I need is for the `__str__()` method to print the data from my class, not the `getQuery()` method. I am majorly confused on how to use `__str__()`.

I also want to pass on the attributes `self.content_data` and `self.stats` to the video class.  Would I inherit everything from `Query` to `Video`?
Thanks for any help... Im new to using Classes so I could use some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__str__` and `__repr__` methods must return a string, so all you need to do is:

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.content_data)
```

> Would I inherit everything from Query to Video?

Yes you would, all public attributes and methods will be inherited.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help! However, I tried that and it prints an empty list instead of the data that should be appended to it... Is the self.content_data in __init__() in a different scope that the self.content_data in getQuery()?

Comment: `self.content_data` is the same object in every method since `self` is the same. So the question you should be asking is, why is `self.content_data` an empty list?

Comment: I have no idea because when I print `self.content_data` from inside `getQuery` it prints out a list with the data,  yet when I try to access the variable with `__str__()` it is empty. I will keep playing around with it. I'm definitely approaching this wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Kindall, you were totally right.  I had changed something playing around with it and forgot to delete it, thus resolving in the empty list every time I ran it. It now works!